# Highligh data as Range Slider in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My earlier question was highlight column as per slider's single value

[Search specific column of table for highlight table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391032/search-specific-column-of-table-for-highlight-table-data)

Now I have slider with range like from 4-8 it should highlight. below is the code for same.

```
jQuery( "#svoltage-range" ).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range:true,
            min: 2,
            max: 20,
            values: [ 2, 20 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                //jQuery( "#amount5" ).val( ui.value );
                jQuery( "#amount5" ).text( "" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                var columnCol = jQuery("#amount5").parent().prevAll().length;
                // jQuery('#tableData tr.data').hide();
                console.log("low value-->" + ui.values[ 0 ]);
                console.log("high value-->" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
                // remove Classes
                jQuery('#tableData tr.data').each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).find('td:eq('+columnCol+')').removeClass("jquery-colorBG-highLight");  // add
                });

                jQuery('#tableData tr').each(function() {
                    var highlightTD_1 = jQuery(this).find('td:eq('+columnCol+')').filter(function() {
                         return jQuery(this).text() >= ui.values[ 0 ];
                    });
                    highlightTD_1.addClass("jquery-colorBG-highLight");

                    var highlightTD_2 = jQuery(this).find('td:eq('+columnCol+')').filter(function() {
                         return jQuery(this).text() <= ui.values[ 1 ];
                    });
                    highlightTD_2.addClass("jquery-colorBG-highLight");                 
                    //highlightTD.parent().show();
                });



            }
        });
```

But there might be some Issue that it highlight all the fields. How to make highlight only TD which fall in range.

[Live URL](http://wasimshaikh.com/demo/range-slider.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code take all the `td`s which their values are bigger than the min value and all the `td`s which their values are smaller than the max value,this mean **all** the `td`s.

Change to this code:

```
            // remove Classes
            jQuery('#tableData tr.data').each(function() {
                jQuery(this).find('td:eq('+columnCol+')').removeClass("jquery-colorBG-highLight"); 
            });

            //add classes
            jQuery('#tableData tr').each(function() {
                var highlightTD_1 = jQuery(this).find('td:eq('+columnCol+')').filter(function() {
                     return jQuery(this).text() >= ui.values[ 0 ] && jQuery(this).text() <= ui.values[ 1 ];
                });
                highlightTD_1.addClass("jquery-colorBG-highLight");
            });
```